# Is There any Third-Party Compiler for Native C for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, native-code

i know that microsoft removed support for C/C++ for windows phone 7, and that only C# is allowed to develope applications for windows phone 7. 
but i know of a compiler (Pelles C) which supports windows mobile 6.5 and smart phones, i asked on their forum month ago but got no reply.

does anyone know if it supports Windows Phone 7? or any other compiler that supports native development for windows phone 7? doesnt have to be from microsoft.

ps: i dont have windows phone 7 phone, i have 6.5, just wanna know if i coded some applications for my phone, will i be able to port it to windows phone 7 or not

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Windows Phone 7 *only* supports managed applications, unless you can get the app bundled with the phone via a carrier or manufacturer.

Comment: @killercode: Not as far as I'm aware. The point isn't which compiler you use, it's whether you're building a managed application - which is easier for MS to sandbox etc.